# Using modulo operator to alternate between even and odd numbered objects

Tags: c++

[Example Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGyuG.png)

I am new to programming in c++ and I am stuck on this homework problem. I need to draw a grid of trees. The dimensions of this grid must be the parameters of the function. So, if you call forest(2,2) it will make 4 trees, forest (3,5) will render 15. Additionally, the trees need to alternate between pine and tree. I just can't seem to get my forest to match the example screenshot and would love any help to steer me in the right direction.

```
#include "cgt215.h"
#include "demo.h"
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cgt215;

// Place global variables here
int mode = 1;
int framesDrawn = 0;
float secondsPassed = 0;
static int counter;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int parameterX = 5;
int parameterY = 4;

// Declare new functions here
void drawPine(double x, double z);
void drawTree(double x, double z);
void trunk(void);
void modeSwitch(char keyToPress, int modeToSwitchTo);
void forest(int, int);

void renderFrame(float lastFrameDuration) {
// Place interactive/animated drawing code here
enable3d();

//Frames Drawn
framesDrawn++;
secondsPassed += lastFrameDuration;

modeSwitch('w', 2);

if (mode == 2) {
    forest(parameterX,parameterY);
}

void drawPine(double x, double z) {
glPushMatrix();
glTranslated(x, 0.0, z);
    trunk();
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslated(0.0, 15.0, 0.0);
        glScaled(1.0, 0.75, 1.0);
        drawCone();
    glPopMatrix();
glPopMatrix();
return;
}

void drawTree(double x, double z) {
glPushMatrix();
    glTranslated(x, 0.0, z);
    trunk();
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslated(0.0, 40.0, 0.0);
        drawSphere(25.0);
    glPopMatrix();
glPopMatrix();
return;
}

void trunk(void) {
glPushMatrix();
    glScaled(1.0, 4.0, 1.0);
    glRotated(90.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    drawTorus(5.0, 6.0);
glPopMatrix();
}

void modeSwitch(char keyToPress, int modeToSwitchTo) {
if (keyPressed(keyToPress)) {
    mode = modeToSwitchTo;
}
}

void forest(int, int) {
for (x = 0; x < parameterX; x++)
    for (y = 0; y < parameterY; y++)
        if (x % 2 == 0) {
            drawTree(-(9 * 100 / 2) + x * 100, -(9 * 100 / 2) + y * 100);
        else {
        drawPine(-(9 * 100 / 2) + x * 100, -(9 * 100 / 2) + y * 100);
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: Well, one thing that pops out is that there are no calls to `drawPine` in your code.

Comment: Perhaps the task would be easier of you first temporary put the 3d things on hold, and instead solve following task: print a matrix of `P` and `T`? Make sure this works fine, and than you can replace P with 3d Pine and T with 3d Tree (although Pine is indeed a Tree)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at 2D arrangement in ASCII of the trees and pines you want to see.

```
T  P  T  P  T
P  T  P  T  P
T  P  T  P  T
```

The places where `T` are found, (x+y) is even.
The places where `P` are found, (x+y) is odd.

The code must reflect that.

```
void forest(int parameterX, int parameterY) {
    for (x = 0; x < parameterX; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < parameterY; y++) {

            // Check whether x+y is even. not just x
            if ( (x+y) % 2 == 0) {
                drawTree(-(9 * 100 / 2) + x * 100, -(9 * 100 / 2) + y * 100);
            }
            else {
                drawPine( ... );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! That makes way more sense

Comment: I want to add that another option that will extend to negative numbers would be to XOR x and y, and then check the lowest bit i.e. ((x^y) & 1) == 0